# Connecting to cassandra column families using thrift api java

Tags: cassandra, thrift

I have a cassandra single node running with few keyspaces and few column families under it. I want to connect with them using **JAVA - THRIFT API**. I am successful upto describing **cluster_name/cluster_version**/etc. I want to **connect to keyspace and column families** under it.

My current java code looks like:

```
import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.*;
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.*;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.*;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ShowKeyspaces {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws TException, InvalidRequestException,     UnavailableException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NotFoundException {

    TTransport tr = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket("localhost", 9160));
    TProtocol proto = new TBinaryProtocol(tr);
    tr.open();
    Cassandra.Client client = new Cassandra.Client(proto);

    System.out.println("Version : "+client.describe_version());
    System.out.println("cluster name : "+client.describe_cluster_name());

    for ( KsDef keyspace: client.describe_keyspaces() )
    {
        System.out.println("keyspace " +keyspace);
    }

    client.set_keyspace("demodb");

    tr.close();
}
}
```

Any suggestions on hoe do I access column families further?

Comment: It is strongly recommended to use one of the java client libraries, like the DataStax CQL driver, Hector or Astyanax. They provide a lot of necessary functionality (failover, retry, connection pool) and are much simpler to work with.

Comment: I agree with Richard. We were using Hector and lately we migrated to datastax java-driver(https://github.com/datastax/java-driver)

Comment: Ok.. Thank you very much. I have also started using datastax.

Answer (score 0):

Be advised that, AFAIK, tables created using CQL3 are not returned in the schema reported by Thrift. https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/issues/139